# Nutch 2.x integration with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, web-crawler, nutch, graph-databases, data-analysis

I'm going to write a web crawler for a very big site (more than 5 million pages) so I'm considering using `Nutch` for the crawling phase. To ease my analyses over the results of the crawling I was thinking on using the neo4j graph database but apparently `Nutch` doesn't have a data accessor for this database or more precisely, `Apache Gora` the data accessor Nutch uses doesn't.

Is there a solution for this problem or an alternative graph database that integrates with nutch?

Comment: There are many ways of integrating with Neo4j, not sure what Nutch is written in, but for most languages there are [drivers](http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides)

Comment: It's written in Java, but using an adhoc driver would mean I have to rewrite Nutch code to use it, since it uses Apache Gora as data storage.